# AVAudioPlayer is not working in sprite kit scene Xcode 7

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, avplayer, ios9, xcode7

i have been using the following code for playing background music in a sprite kit game and it was working fine in Xcode 6.4 but it throws a exception and crashes the game now:

```
- (void)startBackgroundMusic
{
    NSError *err;
    NSURL *file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"lostinspace.caf" ofType:nil]];
    _backgroundAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:&err];
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"error in audio play %@",[err userInfo]);
        return;
    }
    [_backgroundAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    _backgroundAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [_backgroundAudioPlayer setVolume:0.5];
    [_backgroundAudioPlayer play];
}
```

declaring the above code in didMoveToView as :`[self startBackgroundMusic];`
i have looked up the docs but can't find out what is wrong with what i already have. anyone knows how to fix this issue? below is the counsel out put:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
NSURL *file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"lostinspace.caf" ofType:nil]];
```

Try this:

```
NSURL *file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"lostinspace" ofType:@"caf"]];
```

Comment: your answer was correct. i had to clean the project and shut down and restart the Xcode but it did the trick. thanks.